# Display cumulative value of each column in balloon text

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I built a cumulative line graph using `context.cumulativeCol()` in the `Value` field and I am interested in displaying the cumulated value of the current column in the ballon text.

This is what I have, which only shows the value of the column:

[image]

I tried to change the default value `[[Row]], [[Column]]: [[Value]]` from the Ballon Text field and tried to use something like `context.cumulativeCol()` but I could not achieve my goal.

If it is possible, how am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried to put:

```
return "Cumulative: " + context.cumulativeCol();
```

to the balloon function and it worked fine in the latest version. Perhaps you are trying to return a number instead of a string from the balloon function?

Comment: I've just tried to put :  return "Cumulative: " + context.cumulativeCol(); in the balloon text field but the ballon text doesn't show anymore. I wrote it through the "switch to event input mode".

Comment: Could you provide a version information from the Help -> Version message box?

Comment: Version
icCube Reporting : 6.5 (4541)
icCube Server : 6.5 28-Aug-2017 13:28:55 GMT

Comment: It's a bit outdated, if it's possible, please check the latest version available on the official site(6.5.1)